# changing borderWidth with javascript and including a position offset

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to change the border width of a div over a certain period of time and offset the position of the div an equal amount.
The increment is calculated as: delta width/delta time (time is derived in a for loop)

```
var widthchange = (width2-width1)/(t2-t1)
```

which gives me a value of something like this (for example)

```
widthchange = 2.199999999999843
```

so if I increment the width:

```
___ .style.borderWidth =(current += widthchange)+"px "+current+"px "+current+"px "+current+"px"
```

and offset the positioning (in this case)

```
___.style.top =(current -= widthchange)+"px "+current+"px "+current+"px "+current+"px"
```

the div shakes back and forth slightly as the change occurs.

The problem is that width is rounded to the nearest pixel (I believe) and position is not.
I have tried many combinations of rounding, but unless the increment is a whole number, the width adjustment and the offset are not exactly equal.

Can someone please confirm that rounding to the nearest pixel is what is happening with the width? Or give me any advice on how to make this work properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a fiddle. And yes, I do believe that pixels have to be whole numbers. You can't display a partial pixel.

Comment: this was a poor number to use, but if it had been 2.193333333 ---console.log(___.style.borderWidth) = 2.1934px currentpx curpx curpx      --- so it does round but that's not a whole number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by doing this:

1. calculate the desired movement amount
2. round (or truncate) to an integer value.
3. calculate how many steps with the new integer movement amount
4. calculate how many pixels you will need for a final step to get exactly lined up

The code would look something like this, I think as I whip off some untested code ...

```
var totalWidth = width2-width1; // must be positive
var count = t2-t1; // must be positive
var widthchange = totalWidth/count; 

var iWidthChange = Math.floor(widthchange);
var pixelsToMove = Math.floor(totalWidth / iWidthchange);
var finalPixelsToMove = totalWidth - (pixelsToMove * count);

for (var i=0 ; i < (t2-t1); ++i) {
    ... move one increment of 'pixelsToMove' ...
}
... move one final increment of 'finalPixelsToMove'
```